# How to make an image link in phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

```
<a href="login.html"><img src="images/login.png"></a>
```

how to make the image link point towards login page

```
<?php echo Phalcon\Tag::linkTo(array('login', 'Login Here!'));?>
```

here link is working but how to set image as a link to login please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i found the answer.
we could do like

```
<?php echo Phalcon\Tag::linkTo(array('login', '<img src="images/login.png">'));?>
```

this gave me results the way i wanted. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use linkTo and imageInput together like this:

```
    <?php
    echo $this->tag->linkTo(array(
        array(
            'controller' => 'user',
            'action'=>'login'
        ),
         $this->tag->imageInput(array("src" => "images/login.png"));
    )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ link_to('login', image('images/login.png')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for an answer that will take advantage of the Phalcon\Mvc\Url component and it's setBaseUri / getBaseUri features within volt...

Make sure this is in your bootstrap somewhere

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Url UrlProvider;

$di->set( 'url' , function () use ( $config )
{
    $url = new UrlProvider();
    $url->setBaseUri( 'http://mybaseurl.com/folder/' );
    return $url;
});
```

Then, in any of your templates you can do this:

```
{{ link_to( 'login.html' , image( 'images/login.png' , 'alt': 'The Alternate Text' ))}}
```

Which will render the following:

```
<a href="http://mybaseurl.com/folder/login.html"><img src="http://mybaseurl.com/folder/images/login.png" alt="The Alternate Text"></a>
```

And more info can be found here:
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/url.html